# Is silk thread still being used to prevent oil loss from Lycoming engines?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

A teardown/rebuild video of a [Lycoming O-360](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lycoming_O-360) showed the mechanic laying silk thread along a path where 2 engine parts were to be bolted together$^1$.  This would be, in addition to a gasket, to prevent oil leaks.

It seemed possible to have a grooved seat/O-ring type of arrangement as well.

Laying thread is good, but seems to carry the possibility of human inconsistency.  While watching the rebuild video, with the mechanics following aircraft grade specs and tolerances, the part with the thread had me wondering (along with wiring castle nuts instead of using cotter pins).

Time honored, yes.

Could a new mechanic in training expect to be taught the silk thread art for rebuilds?

$^1$ Another source mentions Hylomar or Loctite

Answer (score 2):

You'll do whatever the [Lycoming overhaul manual](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/http://www.monticellofc.org/aircraft/Lycoming-OH-Manual%202002%20ed.pdf) says to do, and the Lyc overhaul manual still calls for silk thread laid into the gasket compound. It says "non hardening gasket compound" which is that Permatex sticky goo stuff that gets on everything when you use it.

It works really well; no need to improve on it.  Hylomar could work (it was developed by Roll Royce for their engines), but I've seen it extrude from the joint in cases where there is potentially a lot of pressure behind it (I tried it as a pad sealant on my own engine and noticed that happening) and if I was assembling an engine I'd stick with the Permatex and silk.

Comment: Yes, and LocTite might get too brittle.  Being a research person, I would get one engine, machine a groove or two, and try silicone O rings.  But it seems essentially what the silk thread is so ...

Comment: Come to think of it, maybe the engine could carry a few quarts more oil too.

Comment: On the cylinder through studs that clamp the bearing races together, Lyc does use O rings at the case seam to keep oil from running down the stud bore. On the earlier O-290 family, they didn't and just depended on interference between the stud and stud bore in the case. My O-290 as a result leaks oil past the cylinder hold down studs/nuts on 3 cylinders. The only fix is to remove the through stud, ream the bore, and install an oversize one with a fresh interference. That can actually be done in the field, but not worth the hassle for a minor oil leak.

Comment: I little checking came up with fiberglass reinforced silicone gasket material.  But I would extensively test it for many hours.  The silk thread thing I would learn if it helps.

Comment: The problem is the joint is the bearing shell clamping halves, and any clearance between the case mating surfaces has to be carefully controlled. You need the thinnest possible gasket that does the job and can tolerate vibration. Silk thread is ideal, silk being extremely strong..

Comment: I could learn it, and Permatex seems to be similar to some coating formulas.  Also looked at soft brass gaskets in motorcycles.